# How to chain SOCKS proxies?

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

I have a working SOCKS proxy from my laptop (machine A) to machine B:

```
[A]$ ssh -ND 8888 B
```

I can set up Firefox to use SOCKS proxy on the local port 8888, and browsing works. So far so good.

But I also have a SOCKS proxy between machines B and C:

```
[B]$ ssh -ND 8157 C
```

So I can browse on B as if I were on C.

**Is there a way to chain the two proxies so that I'm able to use Firefox locally (on A) while using the connection to C?** That is, somehow forward all Firefox's SOCKS requests all the way from A to C. A and C cannot see each other directly, but I have full root SSH access everywhere. All machines are Debian.

Note that I don't want to forward a single port (like 80), I want a full chained SOCKS proxy.

Comment: Relevant docs: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

Answer (score 13):

on machine B set up the dynamic proxy to machine C

```
ssh -ND 8888 user@C
```

then on machine A

```
ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 user@B
```

This makes the SOCKS connection on Machine B and makes machine B's port 8888 connect-able from localhost port 8888 on machine A.

This may need 3 ssh connections open if you can not directly connect to machine B. If you can connect to machine B you only need  2 and can actually chain the commands if needed.

Answer (score 2):

These are the two solutions I use.

**Public SOCKS proxy**
Start SOCKS proxy on a *public* port on machine B

```
[machineB]$ ssh -ND <public_ip>:8080 user@machineC
```

or, do it from machine A (two hops)

```
[machineA]$ ssh user@machineB ssh -ND <machine_b_public_ip>:8080 user@machineC
```

Then set your browser proxy to  on port 8080

*Note:* Make sure port 8080 is open on machine B's firewall

**Tunnelled Proxy**
Tunnel a localhost SOCKS proxy from Machine B to Machine A

Separate commands:

```
[machineB]$ ssh -ND 8080 user@machineC
[machineA]$ ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 user@machineB
```

or do it in a single shot:

```
  [machineA]$ ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 user@machineB ssh -ND 8080 user@machineC
```

Now set your browser proxy to localhost on port 8080

Answer (score 0):

If you're the person who sets up the SOCKS (i.e. if the B→C connection isn't permanent), you can configure the whole thing in your local *~/.ssh/config*:

```bash
Host c
    HostName c.private.example.com
    DynamicForward 8888
    ProxyJump b

Host b
    HostName b.exposed.example.com

    # This is optional, but you can set up SOCKS on B, too
    DynamicForward 8889
```

Then just `ssh -N c &` from A and let it run in the background. The connection to C will automatically connect to B first, and forward its proxy through the tunnel. You can also ask B to make its own proxy, too, if that's helpful for some reason.

If the B→C connection *is* permanent, just forward the B SOCKS port back to A like [exussum suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27138147/241211).

```
Host b
    HostName b.exposed.example.com
    LocalForward 8888 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Answer (score -1):

you could reverse ssh from machine a to machine b then port it to  machine c ie
machine c

```
ssh -R 6333:localhost:22 user@machine_b_ip
```

this will connect machine c to b through encrypted tunnel and listen on port 22 now anything connected to port 6333 on machine b will be sent to machine_c_ip on port 22

now connect from machine a to b

```
ssh user_oof_machine_c@machine_b -p 6333
```

now your connected to machine b on port 6333 anything sent from machine c will be forwarded to machine a

you could reverse to process on different ports to run cmds from a to c

i know this aint sock chaining but is a hack for the problem